# Left eigenvectors of a non-normal matrix from right eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a diagonalizable non-normal matrix is it possible to find left eigenvectors solely from right eigenvectors?
If this sounds too general or no clear statement can be made about this, I can provide a kind of example that is of interest, but I, personally, do not quite remember anything on that.

Comment: The question has been asked and answered on this site before. A Google search for *left and right eigenvectors* should turn up some instances.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, we can write: $A = R\Lambda R^{-1}$, where $R$ is the matrix whose columns are the right eigenvectors of $A$.

We define the matrix $L=R^{-1}$. So we have $A = L^{-1}\Lambda L$. The left eigenvectors will be the rows of $L$. To see why, take $\vec v$ to be any row, say the $j$th row. (So $\vec v$ is a row vector.) Then: $\vec vL^{-1} = \hat e_j$ (the $j$th 1-hot row vector) This can be seen by noting that $LL^{-1}=I$, and just looking at the $j$th row of that computation in particular. Finally, we have:

$$
\vec vA = \vec v L^{-1}\Lambda L = \hat e_j\Lambda L = \hat e_j \lambda_j L = \lambda_j \vec v
$$

This shows that $\vec v$ is a left eigenvector.